# How to change all $ to jQuery where some variable name starts from $ in some Jquery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I learned from [this article](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) that to avoid confliction between javascript libraries, use  `jQuery.noConflict();` function just before `jQuery(document).ready ( function () { })`  and replace `jQuery` at all instance of `$`

but i have seen many jQuery plugin where `$` is used with variable declaration???

here is an example on [this link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs)  on below section

```
  How to...
  [edit]
  ...retrieve the index of the currently selected tab

   var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();
   var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected'); // => 0
```

now i m really confused how to replace `$` with `jQuery` in var `$tabs`??

first of all tell me how can we use `jQuery` instead of `$` in above example and

what is the logic behind declaring variable starting with `$` in javascript?? ( although this is  a PHP varaible decalarion syntax)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$tabs` is just a variable name. That's because javascript accepts a `$` as part of a variable.
You can also use variables like `my$var = 10` or `my$other$var$ = 20`.

To use `jQuery`instead of `$` just substitute it in your code:

```
var x = $('#mydiv')
```

becomes

```
var x = jQuery('#mydiv')
```

Comment: Oh i see, means `$tabs` is just a normal javascript variable, not a jQuery binded variable?

Comment: Yes, don't be confused about `$`: it's just a character. That code could also have been like this `var tabs = $('#example').tabs()` I guess prefixing variables whose value is a jquery object with `$` is just a reminder for the developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript variable names start with a letter, $, or underscore.

http://javascript.about.com/od/variablesandoperators/a/vop04.htm

so $tabs is a normal variable and has nothing to do with jQuery.

Like javascript many other languages allow usage of $ in variable names.

You can refer this answer [why does several javascript libraries use $ for one or other use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155979/why-does-several-javascript-libraries-use-for-one-or-other-use) for wonderful explanation of why $ is used in javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the link Sushil