# What is the purpose of the $ operator in a javascript function declaration?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would a javascript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)
>   [Can someone explain the dollar sign in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

I was looking at a js tutorial where several of the functions where declared with a $ in front of them. I have done some on-line searching but can find no reference to this. Here is an example I created myself:

```
var $x = function(q)
{
  return q*q;
}

var $y = function()
{
  alert($x(10));
}
```

When I call $y from a webpage I get an alert with 100, which is what I expect. So, what, if anything, is the $ for?

Comment: It's a valid character. They could have called them `Cx` and `Cy`.

Comment: May be this answer can give you some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155979/why-does-several-javascript-libraries-use-for-one-or-other-use

Answer (score 2):

I don't think $ means anything special, the tutorial just decided to name the function $x and $y

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything special unless you've included jQuery. Generally, I've seen $ used in the beginning of variables to mark them as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is one of the allowed signs for names of variables in JavaScript. It is not an operator.

As [some other answer on SO mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names/1661249#1661249), allowed characters are: `[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*`.

So, this is not an operator, and can be used to distinguish some variables from other variables.

When it comes to single dolar sign (`$`, without any other letter), this is common as alias for `jQuery` function, if you have installed jQuery and stick with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, serves no purpose. You can remove it an simply do y(10); or x(10);

For example Microsoft introduced $find as a shorthand for document.getElementById